# Z-Order of plots pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Simple question:

I can’t seem to control the z-order (i.e. which comes in front, which comes in the back) of the plots in a 2D axis.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[only marks] table {
      0 2
      1 1
      2 2
    };
    \addplot+[mark=none, line width=2pt] table {
      0 2
      1 1
      2 2
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obligatory screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The problem here is that the first plot, `only marks` *always* comes in front of the other plot. If I reverse the order of the respective `\addplot` commands then the colours and marks are switched but *not* the order of the plots. That is, the `only marks` are still in front of the line.

How can I change this?

(Yes, I need two separate plots here since the line will actually be a regression curve that uses different data but there is a huge overlap and the curve is barely visible below the point cloud).

Comment: That even ignores the `pgfonlayer` environment!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works if you set the option `clip marker paths`:

```
\begin{axis}[clip marker paths=true]
```

That might actually be an unintended side effect of the option.

Comment: So we may assume that it’s a bug then? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I think you should just ask Christian directly. Maybe he is willing to implement a documented option to control the z-order of markers.

Comment: Thanks -- adding the axis option solves the corresponding problem in matlab2tikz as well.

Answer (score 0):

For it worked using

```
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual,]
```

Comment: Your answer may works, but for test it we be very glad to have a complete MWE (for example using recent `pgfplots`), by which we can test your suggestion.