# Shading a region to the left of a parabola

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to draw the parabola x=y^2 in the square box [-2,2] x [-2,2]. The parabola partitions the box into two pieces, and I want to shade the region to the left of it, i.e. the set of points (x,y) with y  between -2 and 2 and x< y^2. I've come across the command `\fillbetween`, but couldn't find an example where they shade the region between two curves of the form x=f(y). I would appreciate any help on how to do this. Thank!

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question. You need to provide a MWE, a picture of what you want and describe what you have tried. For me it seems you want the most basic functionality of the `fill`option or `\fillbetween`!? Have you read about it? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/pgfplots-how-to-fill-bounded-area-under-a-curve-using-addplot-and-fill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact there is no need for the `fillbetween` library to solve your problem. Here I present the "complicated" solution where the normal plot should be on top of the axis, so we need to put the filling *behind* the axis to not overdraw it.

If it is also ok for you that the axis is on top of the plot you could just state `axis on top` in the `axis` environment options and remove all the "layer" stuff.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
% (adapted from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514)
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % define an additional layer for the "filling"
        % (Don't forget to add `main' somewhere in that list!!)
        layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
            background,
            main,
        }{
            % you could state styles here which should be moved to
            % corresponding layers, but that is not necessary here.
            % That is why we don't state anything here
        },
        % activate the newly created layer set
        set layers=my layer set,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=2,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            domain=-sqrt(2):sqrt(2),
            smooth,
            axis lines=center,
            % change `clip mode' to `individual' to avoid unwanted clipping
            clip mode=individual,
        ]
            % if you need everything colored expect to the right of the curve
            \addplot [
                draw=none,
                fill=red!10,
                % with `on layer' you can state the layer where the
                % plot should be drawn on
                on layer=background,
            ] (x^2,x)
                |- (rel axis cs:0,1)
                |- (rel axis cs:1,0)
                -- cycle
            ;
            % if you need only everything left of the curve
            % (but not above and below it)
            \addplot [
                draw=none,
                fill=red!20,
                on layer=background,
            ] (x^2,x)
                -| (rel axis cs:0,0.5)
                |- cycle
            ;
            % the plot itself
            \addplot [very thick,red] (x^2,x);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, algebraic, arrowinset=0.125, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.15,-2.1)(2,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, arrows =-> ](0,0)(-2.15,- 2.1)(2, 2) [$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
    \uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
    \pnodes{A}(-2.25,2.25)(2.25,2.25)(2.25,1.5)(2.25,-1.5)(2.25,-2.25)(-2.25,-2.25)
    \psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed3, plotpoints=100}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=IndianRed3!20, opacity=0.25]{
        \psline[linewidth=0pt](A0)(A1)(A2)
        \parametricplot{1.5}{-1.5}{t^2 | t}%
        \psline(A3)(A4)(A5)\closepath}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]