# How to order/arrange plots in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have four plots with one plot having a legend entry. As the legend entry takes the style of the first plot. I have to place it above all other plots. But placing the command above all other plots makes the plot go behind other plots graphically.

***How can I order the first plot to be on top of the other plots?*** As an example I have shown only four plots. There will be many plots, and I don't want to complicate it much with styles.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents*}{pgfplots.dat}
T   A  B  C
1.42857     6.616   6.697   6.782
1.40845     5.413   5.487   5.564
1.38889     4.544   4.612   4.684
1.36986     3.916   3.982   4.052
1.35135     3.469   3.534   3.603
1.33333     3.158   3.224   3.294
1.31579     2.954   3.022   3.094
1.29870     2.838   2.909   2.983
1.28205     2.795   2.870   2.949
1.26582     2.818   2.898   2.984
1.25000     2.905   2.992   3.085
1.23457     3.057   3.153   3.255
1.21951     3.278   3.385   3.499
1.20482     3.571   3.69    3.816
1.19048     3.922   4.052   4.188
1.17647     4.296   4.433   4.576
1.16279     4.645   4.783   4.927
1.14943     4.921   5.054   5.193
1.13636     5.085   5.208   5.335
1.12360     5.114   5.222   5.333
1.11111     5.007   5.097   5.19
1.09890     4.784   4.858   4.933
1.08696     4.477   4.536   4.596
1.07527     4.121   4.167   4.214
1.06383     3.742   3.778   3.815
1.05263     3.364   3.392   3.42
1.04167     3.001   3.022   3.043
1.03093     2.661   2.677   2.694
1.02041     2.35    2.362   2.375
1.01010     2.069   2.079   2.089
1.00000     1.819   1.827   1.834
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        xmin=1.10,
        xmax=1.4,
        ymin=2.0,
        ymax=7.0,
        ]
        \addplot [solid,red,line width = 2.0] coordinates {(1.25,10) (1.25,0.01)};
        \addlegendentry{Case 1}        
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0] table[x=T,y=A,mark=] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0] table[x=T,y=B,mark=] {pgfplots.dat};
        \addplot [smooth,line width = 1.0] table[x=T,y=C,mark=] {pgfplots.dat};

    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: drawing it last?

Comment: But then the legend takes the first plot style.

Comment: not if you add `forget plot` to the ones you don't want. Or you can use `set layers`

Comment: @nxkryptor, as an example for `set layers` have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514

Comment: I tried the suggested answer. But now the vertical line moves outside the plot. I have updated the question.

Comment: Goit it! I missed the clipping command.

Comment: @StefanPinnow The suggested answer works, but now the ticks are below the plots. If I use 'axis on top=true' the foreground plots are missing.

Comment: @nxkryptor, have a look at [section 4.27 in the PGFPlots manual (v1.15)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=405). There you find `[set layers]` and also how you can change the layer of of graphical elements like the ticks.