# Mark areas in stacked bar plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, dateplot

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot while marking (connected) parts of it.

The `axis cs` approach seems to work in this case, but there are two problems which I am facing:

1. The outline is mostly invisible. I tried experimenting with `pgfonlayer`, but without success. I want it to be visible completely.
2. The outline is too small. It matches the `xtick`s, but not the `ybar` area itself which looks a bit odd.

How can I fix these problems?

This is my current code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ybar stacked,
        width=4cm,
        height=4cm,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xticklabel={\minute},
        xmin={2020-04-21 15:00},
        xmax={2020-04-21 15:10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=3,
        enlarge y limits=0.025,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        xtick={2020-04-21 15:00,2020-04-21 15:10},
    ]
    \addplot+[%
        draw=none,
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},1)
    };
    \addplot+[%
        draw=none
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},0)
    };

    \draw[densely dotted,thick] (axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:01},0) rectangle (axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:05},1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

Comment: I tried to play a bit with the  `calc` library and the bar widths, but I guess the compatibility is not complete with the `datetime` library

Comment: Problem 1 is, because `stacked` plots are drawn in **reverse** order. So just move the `\draw` command before the first `\addplot` command. There is no need for layers. Problem 2 is already solved by [BambOo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539837/95441).

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the drawing order. But the linked answer does not provide a real solution to the second problem for now, as it still says that there are computation errors. While doing some additional experiments based on BambOo's explanation I was able to get it to work using `($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:01},0)-(\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$) rectangle ($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:05},1)+(\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$)`. Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point can be solved using layers, see e.g.  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514/141947) for instance. My proposal directly comes from there. 
The second point is due to the `bar width` that is not accounted for. You can see this if you increase the size of the plot. I wanted to shift the rectangle points with `\pgfplotbarwidth` , but the computation seems to fail because of the dates, and I could not figure why.

Hope this gives information for someone else to solve this.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514/141947
\pgfplotsset{
    % define the layers you need.
    % (Don't forget to add `main' somewhere in that list!!)
    layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
        background,
        main,
        foreground
    }{
        % you could state styles here which should be moved to
        % corresponding layers, but that is not necessary here.
        % That is why wo don't state anything here
    },
    % activate the newly created layer set
    set layers=my layer set,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ybar stacked,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xticklabel={\Hour:\minute},
        xmin={2020-04-21 15:00},
        xmax={2020-04-21 15:10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=3,
        enlarge y limits=0.025,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        bar width=5mm
        %xtick={2020-04-21 15:00,2020-04-21 15:10},
    ]
    \addplot+[%
    on layer=background,
        draw=none,
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},1)
    };
    \addplot+[%
    on layer=background,
        draw=none
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},0)
    };
    \draw[densely dotted,thick,on layer=foreground] (axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:01},0) rectangle (axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:05},1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is an updated version, I believe there are missing interfaces between `bar plot`s and `datetime`. Specifically one should be able to use a unit for `bar width` which fails in this case. So I played a bit with values to obtain something *correct*. Use `(+/-\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)` shifts to account for the bar width. Pay attention to use `0pt` and not `0` otherwise the compilation fails.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514/141947
\pgfplotsset{
    % define the layers you need.
    % (Don't forget to add `main' somewhere in that list!!)
    layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
        background,
        main,
        foreground
    }{
        % you could state styles here which should be moved to
        % corresponding layers, but that is not necessary here.
        % That is why wo don't state anything here
    },
    % activate the newly created layer set
    set layers=my layer set,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ybar stacked,
        width=4cm,
        height=4cm,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xticklabel={\Hour:\minute},
        xmin={2020-04-21 15:00},
        xmax={2020-04-21 15:10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=3,
        enlarge y limits=0.025,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        bar width=2.1mm,
        bar shift=0*\pgfplotbarwidth/2,
        xtick=data,
        xtick={2020-04-21 15:00,2020-04-21 15:10},
    ]
    \addplot+[%
    on layer=background,
        draw=none,
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},1)
    };
    \addplot+[%
    on layer=background,
        draw=none
    ] coordinates {
        ({2020-04-21 15:00},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:01},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:02},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:03},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:04},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:05},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:06},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:07},1)
        ({2020-04-21 15:08},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:09},0)
        ({2020-04-21 15:10},0)
    };
    \draw[densely dotted,thick,on layer=foreground] ($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:01},0) + (-\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$) rectangle ($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:05},1) + (\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like `($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:01},0)-(\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$) rectangle ($(axis cs:{2020-04-21 15:05},1)+(\pgfplotbarwidth/2,0pt)$)` works for the rectangle. Found this while doing some experiments based on your explanation.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh yep, it works indeed. I tried with a `0` not `0pt` yshift. Thanks fo the feedback. I really think something is broken between `datetime` and `bar` plots

Comment: @BambOo, feel free to add an issue to the [PGFPlots repository](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues) (which has moved to GitHub). It is absolutely possible that there is a missing interface between `bar` plots and the `datetime` library.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the update on the new repository. However (and unfortunately) the last issues I posted are still not solved (already related to bar plots) so maybe you are a bit occupied at the moment.

Comment: @BambOo, I am sorry. Although I am member of the developers I am just the "helper" guy to keep a bit track of stuff. But unfortunately I am unable to program in (La)TeX ... Also when there seems to be almost zero activity in the PGFPlots development that shouldn't mean people should stop reporting issues. And of course if the solution is already known also this should be either stated in the issue or even better be placed as a pull request. Thank you in advance for filing the issue ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I have to admit, I never tried to modify the `pgfplots` or `tikz` source code myself. Maybe I should give it a try I will post the issue tomorrow. Is there a specific procedure for contribution ?

Comment: @BambOo, filing an issue on GitHub is the same as filing bugs etc. on SourceForge. And when I am not mistaken *that* you have already done, right? If not: Be as specific as possible with the description of the bug; add an MWE and possible ideas for a solution, if you have one/some.<br>  If you have a *real* solution (for the source code) the same holds as in my previous comment. Many thanks in advance again!!

Comment: @StefanPinnow, Yes, I know how to post an issue ^^ . I meant more in terms of coding contribution. More specifically, If one proposes a pull request, that means the repo must have been cloned, some modifications made locally on the clone and tested before proposing the pull request. I guess, as latex packages are mostly scripts it may be simple, but for some more complex projects some parts of code have to be compiled. So there is sort of a contribution procedure to help people contribute.

Comment: @BambOo, you are right, that is the way to go (clone, make changes, test, pull request). Unfortunately I can't tell you at the moment how to test correctly. Hmenke started setting up Travis CI (see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/pull/347), but I know that there are also unit tests for a lot of stuff. For the latter I have no idea how to trigger them ... To sum up: Just do your best ;)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you already have filed an issue ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107221/discussion-between-bamboo-and-stefan-pinnow).