# How to draw a line before points in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line

I have a problem with drawn lines in a tikz plot. It feels like the solution should be really simple but I don't know how to solve it. When I plot data points and a line, the line is behind the data points, even though the code for the line comes after the code for the points and I need the line before the points. I didn't write this myself, but used the matlab2tikz function to generate the code, if this is relevant.

Here is a picture how it looks like:
[image]

And here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.633in,
height=2.11in,
at={(0.609in,0.492in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=30.000,
xmax=80.000,
xlabel style={font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\color{white!15!black}\selectfont},
xlabel={Measurement},
ymin=30.000,
ymax=80.000,
ylabel style={font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\color{white!15!black}\selectfont},
ylabel={Prediction},
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, line width=1.0pt, only marks, mark size=3.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid,             fill=blue, draw=black}, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
72.000  72.047\\
72.000  71.995\\
68.000  68.002\\
69.000  70.999\\
68.000  67.503\\
65.000  65.175\\
73.000  72.323\\
73.000  71.995\\
70.000  65.484\\
54.000  57.819\\
38.000  37.534\\
};
\addplot [color=red, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
30.000  30.000\\
80.000  80.000\\
};
\node[right, align=left, font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont]
at (axis cs:60,41) {$\overline{R^{2}}=0.949$};
\node[right, align=left, font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont]
at (axis cs:55.1,36) {$RMSE = 2.484$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: This helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350514/31034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot on different layers and arrange them as explained in this post: [PGFPlots: Understanding how to draw plots on different layers and arrange them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350458/pgfplots-understanding-how-to-draw-plots-on-different-layers-and-arrange-them/350514#350514).

An alternate way is to plot the line in a different `axis` environment as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.633in, height=2.11in,
at={(0.609in,0.492in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=30.000, xmax=80.000,
xlabel style={font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\color{white!15!black}\selectfont},
xlabel={Measurement},
ymin=30.000, ymax=80.000,
ylabel style={font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\color{white!15!black}\selectfont},
ylabel={Prediction},
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, line width=1.0pt, only marks, mark size=3.5pt, mark=*, mark options={solid,             fill=blue, draw=black}, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
72.000  72.047\\
72.000  71.995\\
68.000  68.002\\
69.000  70.999\\
68.000  67.503\\
65.000  65.175\\
73.000  72.323\\
73.000  71.995\\
70.000  65.484\\
54.000  57.819\\
38.000  37.534\\
};
\addplot [color=red, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
30.000  30.000\\
80.000  80.000\\
};
\node[right, align=left, font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont]
at (axis cs:60,41) {$\overline{R^{2}}=0.949$};
\node[right, align=left, font=\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont]
at (axis cs:55.1,36) {$RMSE = 2.484$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
width=3.633in,height=2.11in,
at={(0.609in,0.492in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=30.000,xmax=80.000,
ymin=30.000,ymax=80.000,
ticks=none
]
\addplot [color=red, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
30.000  30.000\\
80.000  80.000\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]