# Overlap filled area plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a series of plots that are filled with `fill between`. After I produce the plots, I draw a line which goes from the center of the area to an external point. I would like the line to disappear under a certain area. Until now I was able to produce just this

[image]

based on the following instructions

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:pi/2,
             xmin=-1.5, xmax=2]

\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=A, 
        thick,
        color=blue,
        ]  {sin(deg(x))};

\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=B, 
        thick,
        color=green,
        ]  {2*sin(deg(x))};
        
\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=C, 
        thick,
        color=red,
        ]  {3*sin(deg(x))};                
              
\addplot[forget plot, name path=axis,domain=0:pi/2]{0};

\addplot[red]   fill between[of=C and axis];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=B and axis];
\addplot[blue]  fill between[of=A and axis];

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] coordinates { (-0.5,0.5) (1,0.5)}; 

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] coordinates { (-0.5,1) (1,1)}; 

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] coordinates { (-0.5,2) (1,2)};
  
\node at (axis cs:-0.5,0.5) [anchor=east] {$sin(x)$};      
\node at (axis cs:-0.5,1) [anchor=east] {$2*sin(x)$};   
\node at (axis cs:-0.5,2) [anchor=east] {$3*sin(x)$};   

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "disappear under a certain area"? Could you add a sketch to your image to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello Stefan, thank you for your reply. For example, I want the black line associated with sin(x) to be visible over the red and green are, while disappearing under the blue one, and so on for the other lines. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you comment to question correctly, than you after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:pi/2,
             xmin=-1.5, xmax=2,
             domain=0:pi/2,
             trig format=rad,
             ]
\addplot[name path=A, thick]     {sin(x)};
\addplot[name path=B, draw=none]   {2*sin(x)};
\addplot[name path=C, draw=none]    {3*sin(x)};

\addplot[name path=axis]            {0};

\addplot[red, semitransparent]   fill between[of=C and axis];
\addplot[green, semitransparent] fill between[of=B and axis];
\addplot[blue, semitransparent]  fill between[of=A and axis];

\draw   (1,0.50) -- (-0.5,0.50) node[left] {$\sin(x)$} 
        (1,1.25) -- (-0.5,1.25) node[left] {$2*\sin(x)$} 
        (1,2.00) -- (-0.5,2.00) node[left] {$3*\sin(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For fill color is used `semitransparent` option that curve of function `sin(x)` is better visible. In diagram code I also took liberty for make it shorter and simpler.

**Addendum (1):**
You may liked diagram with tick of function domain in shown in radians:

[image]

for this diagram you only need to add to `axis` option the following code lines:

```
             xtick={0, pi/6, pi/3, pi/2},
             xticklabels={0,$\pi/6$,$\pi/3$,$\pi/2$},
             xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
```

**Addendum (2):**
Considering OP comment below this answer, which make problem more clear, the one of possible (general) solution is employ Zi*k*Z library `intersections`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:pi/2,
             xmin=-1.5, xmax=2,
             xtick={0, pi/6, pi/3, pi/2},
             xticklabels={0,$\pi/6$,$\pi/3$,$\pi/2$},
             xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
             domain=0:pi/2,
             trig format=rad,
every axis plot post/.append style={draw=none}             
            ]
\addplot[name path=A]   {sin(x)};
\addplot[name path=B]   {2*sin(x)};
\addplot[name path=C]    {3*sin(x)};

\addplot[name path=axis]            {0};

\addplot[red, semitransparent]   fill between[of=C and axis];
\addplot[green, semitransparent] fill between[of=B and axis];
\addplot[blue, semitransparent]  fill between[of=A and axis];

\path [name path=A1] (-0.5,0.50) node[left] (a) {$\sin(x)$} -- (pi/2,0.50); 
\path [name path=B1] (-0.5,1.25) node[left] (b) {$\sin(x)$} -- (pi/2,1.25);
\path [name path=C1] (-0.5,2.00) node[left] (c) {$\sin(x)$} -- (pi/2,2.00);

\draw [name intersections={of=A and A1, by=a1}] (a) -- (a1);
\draw [name intersections={of=B and B1, by=b1}] (b) -- (b1);
\draw [name intersections={of=C and C1, by=c1}] (c) -- (c1);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Corrected are errors in naming of x ticks.

Comment: Hello Zarco, probably my request was not really clear. What I would like is the horizontal lines connecting one area to the labels (sin(x), 2*sin(x) or 3*sin(x)) to disappear under the filled area.

Comment: It's then a problem of layers. This will definitely help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350458/pgfplots-understanding-how-to-draw-plots-on-different-layers-and-arrange-them

Comment: @Fly, sorry, but now is obvious that your question is not clear at all.

Comment: @JeT, yes, this is one promising way, another possibilities is use of `intersections` library. I will try to write addendum ASAP.

Comment: @Fly, see  addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Zarko, but I tried to compile your code and I receive the error "No shape named `intersection-1' is known"

Comment: @Fly, with my code as are in addendum, this cannot be a case (tested again).

Comment: The error was had origin to the compat version wich on my machine is 1.15. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If I have well understood the request, you need to adjust the x coordinate so that it corresponds to a point on the graph. For this we have to use the inverse functions `asin(y)`,  `asin(y/2)` and `asin(y/3)`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[domain=0:pi/2,
             xmin=-1.5, xmax=2]
             


\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=A, 
        thick,
        color=blue,
        ]  {sin(deg(x))};

\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=B, 
        thick,
        color=green,
        ]  {2*sin(deg(x))};
        
\addplot[forget plot,
        name path=C, 
        thick,
        color=red,
        ]  {3*sin(deg(x))};                
              
\addplot[forget plot, name path=axis,domain=0:pi/2]{0};

\addplot[red]   fill between[of=C and axis];
\addplot[green] fill between[of=B and axis];
\addplot[blue]  fill between[of=A and axis];

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] 
         coordinates { (-0.5,0.5) (rad(asin(0.5)),0.5)}; % <-----------

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] 
         coordinates { (-0.5,1) (rad(asin(1/2)),1)}; % <-------------

\addplot [forget plot, mark=none,  black] 
         coordinates { (-0.5,2) (rad(asin(2/3)),2)};% <-----------------
  
\node at(axis cs:-0.5,0.5)[anchor=east] {$sin(x)$};      
\node at (axis cs:-0.5,1) [anchor=east]{$2*sin(x)$};   
\node at (axis cs:-0.5,2) [anchor=east]{$3*sin(x)$};   

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Adif, thank you for the reply. It's exactly what I was searching, but what about a more general approach? In reality my curves are defined not by analytical functions.

Comment: @Fly If the functions are defined by a list of coordinates then choose one of them and draw a line from this point to the text node