# pgfplots: Problem with layers when plotting single point

Tags: pgfplots, pgflayers

I've encountered a problem in which plotting a single point does not respect user-defined layers. Take the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  % define the layers you need.
  % (Don't forget to add `main' somewhere in that list!!)
  layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
      back,
      main,
      fore
  }{
  % you could state styles here which should be moved to
  % corresponding layers, but that is not necessary here.
  % That is why we don't state anything here
  },
  % activate the newly created layer set
  set layers=my layer set,
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
0 0
0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
-0.5 0.5
 0.5 0.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data3.dat}
0 0.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[draw=black,on layer=back] plot[] file {data1.dat};
\addplot[draw=black,mark=*,on layer=back] plot[] file {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=red,on layer=main] plot[] file {data2.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The layer definition follows that in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350458/47927). Briefly put, I draw a vertical black line in the back layer, a horizontal red line in the main layer, and then add a black point at the intersection of the two lines in the back layer. However, what I get is this (blown-up):

[image]

Unless I misunderstand something very basic about layers or how they are defined, this is wrong because the red line should be on top. Interestingly, if I change the following command

```
\addplot[draw=red,on layer=main] plot[] file {data2.dat};
```

to use the "fore" layer (i.e., two layers on top of the "back" layer),

```
\addplot[draw=red,on layer=fore] plot[] file {data2.dat};
```

then it works properly:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markers behave a bit special in PGFPlots as they don't necessarily adhere to the layer of the relevant plot. But you can force them to do so using the option `mark layer=like plot` on the relevant `\addplot` macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  % define the layers you need.
  % (Don't forget to add `main' somewhere in that list!!)
  layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
      back,
      main,
      fore
  }{
  % you could state styles here which should be moved to
  % corresponding layers, but that is not necessary here.
  % That is why we don't state anything here
  },
  % activate the newly created layer set
  set layers=my layer set,
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
0 0
0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
-0.5 0.5
 0.5 0.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data3.dat}
0 0.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[draw=black,on layer=back] plot[] file {data1.dat};
\addplot[draw=black,mark=*,on layer=back,mark layer=like plot] plot[] file {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=red,on layer=main] plot[] file {data2.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me try to explain what is going on with markers: As far as In understand the relevant parts from the manual, the problem is that markers are by default on a separate layer which is above other plots. The option `clip mode` is typically set to `global` which means that all plots are clipped at the borders. However, markers behave differently (at least if `clip marker paths` is set to `false` which is the default). The [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) states (in section 2.20.2 "Clipping", item `/pgfplots/clip mode=global|individual`):

> In order to avoid clipped marker paths, any markers are processed after the clip path has been closed, i.e. on a separate layer.

Therefore, markers sit above the plots, even above plots that are drawn after those which they belong to. The default option `mark layer=auto` represents this default behavior, but you can override it and state explicitly the layer on which the markers should be drawn (or attach the markers to the layer of the plot using the `like plot` value).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.